# Regex; match on one word OR two words and a colon

Tags: regex

I'm looking to match text where there can be 1 word `Foo:`or 2 words `Foo Bar:`--note the whitespace as well

This is the pattern I have so far:

```
(([A-Z])\w+: )|(([A-Z])\w+\s([A-Z])\w+: )
```

When I do some tests in http://regexr.com/, It can come back matching `Foo:` but never sees `Foo Bar:`

Any suggestions for a regex noob are appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
\w+(\s\w+)?\:\s
```

I wasn't sure if you needed to match on capital letters specifically... it didn't say so in your question text but does imply it in your Regex. If so, try this:

```
[A-Z]\w*(\s[A-Z]\w*)?\:\s
```

Comment: Awesome, yup this is _EXACTLY_ what I was looking to do